# Is there a function $f:{\mathbb N}\to{\mathbb N}$ that is neither injective nor surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Is there a function $f:{\mathbb N}\to{\mathbb N}$ that is neither injective nor surjective ?

---

I came up with $n\mapsto\sin n$ as not all outputs are mapped and some inputs have the same output, but then I realized $\sin n$ doesn't produce a natural number. I have to map the natural numbers to the natural numbers.

I also came up with other ones but they always seem to be total and injective or total and subjective.

Comment: Do you mean a total function, maybe?

Comment: I think a total relation is one where every pair of elements is comparable. So to speak, for every $x,y$ either $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$ belongs in the relation. He now wants a non-injective relation i.e. two elements with same second component but different first component, but also non-surjective  i.e. there is some natural number that is not the second component of any element. That is what I think.

Comment: I was suppose to look for a relation from the natural set to the natural set with the above condition. So technically a function.

Comment: I think @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг may be right, and you misunderstood what the question was trying to ask (it's certainly far more interesting that way).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Well, there is no total relation that is non-surjective relation: for it to be total, it needs to be reflexive, and is therefore automatically surjective.

Comment: @Bram28 I had not thought about that! Hence,you are right. However, suppose we only insist the above for all $a \neq b$. Then, can you solve the question?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Hmmm, how about the $<$ relation?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, that's right! It's not injective, example both $1,2$ are less than $3$. Nothing is less than $1$, so it is not surjective, but then it is true that $a,b$ are always comparable if unequal.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When in doubt, don't do anything complicated: $$f(n)=17.$$ (Of course, you may have additional conditions you want satisfied, but you haven't mentioned them.)

Comment: @JozemiteApps Yes it does. It takes in a natural number and spits out a natural number. What do you think the phrase means?

Comment: @JozemiteApps So you're just asking how to express this in the form $f: X\rightarrow Y: x\mapsto y$ (or similar)? I think that's something you can figure out on your own, if you think about it (what do **you** want the domain/codomain to be? can that work?).

Comment: @JozemiteApps What do you think the term surjective means?

Comment: I just finally realized what you did. haha. For some reason I kept thinking I needed to include all codomains on the right side, but I just realized, I don't have to. They are implicitly already in the codomain set, just not mapped to at all.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding codomains. The codomain of a function definitely has to contain all the outputs, but it can also contain more stuff: e.g. the function $f(x)=x^2$ makes sense as a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, but it *also* makes sense as a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$. So think about it: you want something that maps from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. What domain and codomain do you want, then? Do they make sense for this function?

Comment: @JozemiteApps Yup! And they'd better not be since otherwise the function would be injective, which you don't want. (That said, I do think that there is a real chance that you've misinterpreted the question and  астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг had the right interpretation, so I'd go back and make sure.)

Comment: Why not $f(n)=42$?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan I don't feel so bad thinking this to myself now.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan: This question isn't that important. :)

Comment: @NoahSchweber in your last comment: "they'd better not be since otherwise the function would be injective" - I think you mean "surjective". Too bad after such a great explanation !

Comment: That part was easy. Now we have to find out what's special about 17.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It is 10 greater than a reasonable approximation of infinity.

Comment: @Evargalo Oof, quite right! Shame on me, and it's far too late to edit.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan, Peter A. Schneider: Because https://mathoverflow.net/a/285937/27465

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Maybe David C. Kelly and M. Spivak can explain you [about $17$, and yellow pigs (!)](https://www.vinc17.net/yp17/index.en.html)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Oh my, that's absolutely brilliant! It's not what my motivation used to have been, but it was now.

Answer (score 16):

$$n\to\sin n\color{red}\pi$$
<sup>(Actually, this is equivalent to $n\to 0$ and thus in the same vein as Schweber's answer. I couldn't resist tacking on to the function in the question though.)</sup>

Comment: Also, more aligned with OP's initial attempt at solving problem. But I actually up-voted your answer because I learned something new - latex $\color{red}coloring$!

Answer (score 13):

How about $f(n) = n^2-n$?

Total, as $f(n)$ is defined for each $n$

Not injective, as $f(0)=f(1)$

Not surjective, as there is no $n$ such that $f(n)=1$

Comment: This is injective if you consider the "natural numbers" not to include zero.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of fine answers given already, but possibly you'll enjoy this one, too:

$$n\mapsto n(1+\cos n\pi)$$